# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font.getIndexAsInt()

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

An exception occurred in `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font.getIndexAsInt()` when `setFont` invoked.

```
public static CellStyle getFontBoldedUnderlinedCell(SXSSFWorkbook workbook) {
    Font font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setBold(true);
    font.setUnderline(XSSFFont.U_SINGLE);
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFont(font);
    return style;
}
```

My project contains the following libraries.

[image: jar files]

How can I resolve this issue?

**StackTrace:**

```
11:03:00,255 SEVERE com.epic.cmsreports.util.interceptor.AccessControlIntercepter] 
(default task-57) null: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
at com.epic.cmsreports.util.interceptor.AccessControlIntercepter.intercept(AccessControlIntercepter.java:66)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
```

Comment: Post your stack trace with this exception, please.

Comment: [Can I mix POI jars from different versions?](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204) "No. This is not supported.". So do removing poi-3-17.jar and do using poi-4.0.1.jar instead.

Answer (score 1):

According [JavaDoc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html) getIndexAsInt was added in 4.0.0 version.

It is look like, in real you use poi-ooxml < 4.0.0, you should to check do you have only one jar dependencies.

If you use maven or something similar, you need to see dependencies tree.

If you just add jar file to directory, I recommend to search "`org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel`" and "`org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming`" in all your jar files (just using file search), when you find all Font classes, you need to check what version do you have (open jar file as zip archive).